# How to implement synchronous transactional system?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, neo4j, architecture

Let's image that we have a simple endpoint called `CreateEntity` in some `.NET Core` *controller* and we have two services which saves the *entity* to the `Mongo` and `Neo4j` databases (in this particular order).

I want to implement some pattern to make sure that we have *consistent* data.

> Why ?

Because we might have situations when entity is added to `Mongo`, but the call to the `Neo4j` crashes. And that means the data remains inserted in the `Mongo`.

One solution is to use `try-catch` statement for second service call and use compensating transactions for `Mongo` insert. In this case, remove the entity from `Mongo`. Another one could be using a state for entity and put **Pending** as initial state and mark it as **Completed** after `Neo4j` call is made with success.

I also looked over **SAGA** and **2PC** patterns but they are used in asynchronous contexts and across microservices (you know, by communicating between microservices with RabbitMQ, Kafka, Service Bus & other)

But in my case there is a single microservice. Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to wrap your mongo operations in a [transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/).  If the Neo4j fails, roll back the mongo transaction, if it succeeds, commit it.

Comment: What happens if Neo4j succeeds and then the process crashes before committing the Mongo transaction?

Answer (score 1):

[Temporal](https://temporal.io/) open source project can be used to implement compensations and SAGAs in synchronous scenarios. The basic idea of Temporal is that you write your code as a failure of the code that performs remote calls cannot happen. In case of a process failure Temporal is going to migrate the execution to a different machine in exactly the same state as before the crash. The state includes all local variables and blocking calls.
Here is a SAGA example using Temporal Java SDK:

```java
public void bookTrip(String name) {
    // Configure SAGA to run compensation activities in parallel
    Saga.Options sagaOptions = new Saga.Options.Builder().setParallelCompensation(true).build();
    Saga saga = new Saga(sagaOptions);
    try {
      String carReservationID = activities.reserveCar(name);
      saga.addCompensation(activities::cancelCar, carReservationID, name);

      String hotelReservationID = activities.bookHotel(name);
      saga.addCompensation(activities::cancelHotel, hotelReservationID, name);

      String flightReservationID = activities.bookFlight(name);
      saga.addCompensation(activities::cancelFlight, flightReservationID, name);
    } catch (ActivityFailure e) {
      saga.compensate();
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, the [.NET SDK for Temporal](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-dotnet) is still under development as of the summer of 2022. The currently supported languages are Typescript/Javascript, Go, Java, Python & PHP.

For .NET you can also use [Durable Task Framework](https://github.com/Azure/durabletask) and/or [Azure Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) that are based on the same idea as Temporal.

Answer (score 1):

some form of Saga might be useful here. There's plenty of libraries around, and they usually all have a way to deal with "compensating transactions".

Regardless you go for a pre-baked library or not, the flow might be something like this:

- write data to Mongo inside a transaction
- if write is successful, send a message to a queue
- the message consumer takes care of writing to Neo4j

in case the last step fails, send a message to a different queue. Its consumer will take care of removing data from Mongo.

I'd also suggest to use the Outbox pattern to improve the resiliency.

(disclaimer, I'm the author of OpenSleigh, a .NET Saga library)